# Implementing SSAO in Minecraft shaders

Tags: c, shader, minecraft

Thinking it would be fun, I chose Minecraft shaders as the thesis of Computer Graphics my project.

Currently I'm having an issue with something in the shaders though. I've been following [this tutorial](https://saada2006.github.io/minecraft-shader-tutorials/) and I've finished it and created my first shader. However I did not like the look of the shader itself so I wanted to implement SSAO to give some depth to the scene. However, I'm encountering a problem where it just doesn't work. It just darkens the entire scene without darkening edges as it's supposed to.

I've followed some of the code for this here: http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.com/2013/01/ssao-tutorial.html

The current code for calculation the occlusion factor that I have written is this:

```
float AmbientOcclusion(){
    const int kernel_size = 64; // change to 16 to compare
    const float radius = 0.65;
    const float bias = 0.025;

    vec3 kernel[kernel_size];

    for(int i = 0; i<kernel_size ; i++){
        kernel[i] = vec3(
            noise1(1.0),
            noise1(1.0),
            noise1(1.0)*0.5+0.5
        );

        //kernel[i] = normalize(kernel[i]);
        //kernel[i] *= rand(vec2(0.0, 1.0));
        float scale = float(i) / float(kernel_size);
        scale = lerp(0.1f, 1.0f, scale * scale);
        kernel[i] *= scale;
    }

    vec3 normal = normalize( texture2D( colortex1, tex_coords ).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0 );
    
    vec2 NoiseScale = vec2(viewWidth/noiseTextureResolution, viewHeight/noiseTextureResolution);
    
    float depth = texture2D(depthtex0, tex_coords).x;
    vec3 origin = vec3(tex_coords,texture2D(depthtex0, tex_coords)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec4 homogenous = gbufferProjectionInverse * vec4(origin, 1.0);
    origin = homogenous.xyz/homogenous.w;

    float ao = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i<kernel_size; i++){
        vec3 RandomVector = texture2D(noisetex, tex_coords*NoiseScale).rgb;
        
        vec3 tangent = normalize(RandomVector - normal * dot(RandomVector, normal));
        vec3 bitangent = cross(normal, tangent);
        mat3 tbn = mat3(tangent, bitangent, normal);
        vec3 samplePos = tbn*kernel[i];
        samplePos = radius * samplePos + origin;
        //vec3 samplePos = viewPos + RandomVector * kernel[i];

        vec4 intermediaryPos = gbufferProjection * vec4(samplePos, 1.0);
        vec3 offset = intermediaryPos.xyz/intermediaryPos.w;
        offset = offset * 0.5 + 0.5;

        float thisDepth = texture2D(depthtex0, offset.xy).r;

        float rangeCheck = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, radius / abs(origin.z - thisDepth));
        
        ao += (thisDepth >= samplePos.z + bias? 1.0 : 0.0) * rangeCheck;
         
    }

    ao = 1.0 - (ao / kernel_size);

    return ao;
}
```

And I incorporate the occlusion factor at the end of the color calculation in composite.fsh like this:

```
    vec3 diffuse = albedo * ( lightmap_color + NdotL * get_shadow( depth ) + ambient)  ;
  
    /* DRAWBUFFERS:0 */
    
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4( diffuse, 1.0 );
```

Where NdotL is the dot product between the sunPosition and the surface normal, get_shadow is a function for checking whether a surface should cast a shadow or not and ambient is where I incorporate the occlusion factor as `vec3 ambient = (albedo*ao*0.3);`.

Currently, I'm just getting a darker scene, with no visible effect of any ambient occlusion:

[image: AO on]

As opposed to no AO:

[image: AO off]

Is my AO calculation wrong or is my color calculation wrong? Here is the rest of the code from the composite.fsh: https://pastebin.com/vLexyD9i